# How to use variables from another class

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, class, variables

Alright, here we go. I am kinda new with programming and C#, but I'm learning it with John Sharp's *Visual C#: Step By Step* book. (I wonder if that dude's last name is really Sharp)

Anyway, I'm trying to create an application that will help me transpose note. It's a windows forms app and I'm using two classes: *form1.cs* where all the code happens and *vars.cs* where all the variables are stored.

My problem is that I want to use string *vars.noteChosen* and define with *comboBoxNote*'s currently selected item (e.g. C). Whenever I do this, however, when I execute `vars.noteChosen = comboNote.SelectedText;` I get a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error. Any ideas? (comboNote is a combobox)

This is *vars.cs*

```
namespace Transposer
{
    class vars
    {
        public static bool rbTransposeUp = true;
        public static string noteChosen = ""; //
        public static string toTranspose = ""; // 
        public static int note = 0;
        public static string boxResultText = note.ToString();
    }
}
```

and this is a part of *form1.cs*

```
namespace Transposer
{
    public partial class Transposer : Form
    {
        public Transposer()
        {
            vars.noteChosen = comboNote.SelectedText;
            vars.toTranspose = comboNote.Text;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Added it, its a combobox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the lines after the call to `InitializeComponent();` It's this call that is creating the comboNote object.

That is

```
    public Transposer()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); // this constructs the comboNote
        vars.noteChosen = comboNote.SelectedText;
        vars.toTranspose = comboNote.Text;
    }
```

Comment: That should do the trick. The thing is that comboNote is set to `null` until the `InitializeComponent()` method is called. You cannot invoke a property's get or set if the value is null.

Comment: Great. If you look in the form1.designer.cs you can see the InitializeComponent method to see what is going on.